# Python parsing of a Glib.Variant

Tags: python, python-2.7, glib

I have a python2.7 script which obtains a Glib.Variant e.g.

```
>>> s
GLib.Variant('a{sa{sv}}', {'connect': {}, 'type': {'login': <'LoginName'>}, 'ipv6': {}, 'ipv4': {}, 'proxy': {}})
```

How do I parse this to obtain the value of 'login' i.e. 'LoginName' in the above example? (I can find a lot of ref docs online, but no examples to give me a clue to get started).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dbus-python tutorial](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html) has something on [data types](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html#data-types).  Seems like you have a dictionary (GLib) which maps to a dictionary in Python.

So the answer should be:

```
print s['type']['login']
```